# How Can I get UserId from ConnectionId in asp.net identity framework SignalR?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, signalr, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am using Asp.net Identity framework for authentication. 
Now I need the User id of connected client from connectionId or role of connected user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class WhateverHub : Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        //Get the username
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        //Get the UserId
        var claimsIdentity = Context.User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        if (claimsIdentity != null)
        {
            // the principal identity is a claims identity.
            // now we need to find the NameIdentifier claim
            var userIdClaim = claimsIdentity.Claims
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            if (userIdClaim != null)
            {
                var userIdValue = userIdClaim.Value;
            }
        }
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to use the [`[Authorize]`](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization) attribute in your `Hub` class

Comment: I need the user id from connectionID ? Do you know you connectionId in signalr?. I mean any connected client have a unique connection id and I need those coectiondId userId? Do you Understand What I mean ?

Comment: `SignalR ConnectiondId` and `Identity UserId` (primary key from `Users` table) are not the same. What do you need?

Comment: Thank You :) its works now :) can you help me for another question ?

Comment: I Want to active the chatroom while if any Admin User is online. If any admin user is not online any user cant chat . How Can I Do this can you help me please ?

Comment: This is way way too broad. I don't know what a "chatroom" is for you, but I'll assume it's a SignalR group. What you need to do is keep track of all connected user and if they are admin ([using OnConnected, OnDisconnected and OnReconnected](http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/microsoft-asp-net-signalr))