# How to find the User id of connected user to signal R hub Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I am new to Signal R. I want to find the User id of Connected Users to signal R Hub Class on the bases of ids i want to show there online offline status using MVC ASP.NET

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Can I get UserId from ConnectionId in asp.net identity framework SignalR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37065582/how-can-i-get-userid-from-connectionid-in-asp-net-identity-framework-signalr)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Context.ConnectionId.
The rest you have to control by yourself.

Comment: How can control it can you please provide me some help.

Comment: How to return the list of connected id and show it in on view ?